# Python, работа с очень большими числами

Tags: python-3.x, float

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Питоне можно работать с огромными числами, например с числами по 300 - 400 десятичных разрядов? Проблема в следующем, если такое число делить на что либо (или умножать на число с плавающей точкой), выдаёт ошибку: OverflowError: int too large to convert to float,
конечно я понимаю, я бы и сам обалдел от размера числа и знаю, что есть  проблема с числами с плавающей точкой, но мне важна именно десятичная часть результата деления и чем точнее, тем лучше. +, -, **, % и // работают отлично, а вот с умножением на float и с обычным делением - беда. Подскажите пожалуйста какие варианты решения этого вопроса, может библиотеки какие то, или лайфхаки...

Comment: можно попробовать использовать `import fractions`

Comment: спасибо, сейчас погуглю

Comment: Ну или `decimal`

Comment: А так то можно тупо умножить делимое на 10 в степени сколько вам нужно будет десятичных разрядов, разделить на делитель нацело, и взять остаток от деления на это вот 10 в степени, это и будет то, что после запятой должно было быть. В общем, не зная use-case можно много вариантов предложить, не знаю какой больше подойдёт.

Comment: про decimal  я нагуглил, думал, вдруг есть что-то проще

Comment: Да вроде ж куда проще, чем `decimal` )  Хотя, повторюсь, зависит от того, что вы хотите.